# How to verify correct webpage with needed content is loaded in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to coding

I have a table of elements say some mutual funds that needs to be tested. I am having a doubt  if a fund is clicked and opened how to verify  if the page that opened actually had relevant infoabout the fund with out any discrepancy like the page having info of some other fund.

I wrote a block of code to catch 404 & 503 errors but how do I verify the content authenticity. Tried the Page title thing but my fund webpage title looks some what "my company name - product details - mutual fund- fund ID"...the last part fund ID is only thing in title that I can compare of . If I decided to use fund ID should I follow the below thing

Like, if a fund opens get the page title and search for fund ID in the web page like string comparison.is this feasable?

Note all 100 funds opens in same tab I wrote code to pull hrefs of all funds store in array and navigate one by one

Plz help

Comment: Welcome to SO and coding! You need to show what you have tried, looked into, what didn't work as expected and what you actually expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify the **`Page Title`** which reads as `"my company name - product details - mutual fund- fund ID"` with respect to **`fund ID`** you can use the following code block :

```
String title = driver.getTitle();
if(title.endsWith("fund ID"))
    System.out.println("Page Title Matched");
else
    System.out.println("Page Title Matching Failed");
```

---

To verify the presence of the **`fund ID`** in the **`Web Page`**, you can use the following code block by validating the **`fund ID`** in the **`Page Source`**:

```
String source = driver.getPageSource();
if(source.contains("fund ID"))
    System.out.println("Fund ID Validated");
else
    System.out.println("Fund ID Validation Failed");
```

Comment: Hi debanjanB appreciate ur quick reply. But I am looking for something like if I get the page title lets say it is - "Bbfc bank - product details - mutual funds - ASFRDC "

Here I want to test if that ASFRDC - the respective fund ID is present on the webpage either by a string comparison or something. Now major doubt for me here is. 

How do I get just my fund ID from my whole string of title and use it to compare ...also there are like 100 funds in each table so once I compare fund ID and condition is true my code pulla href of other fund and i navigate to other fund and same thing repeats.

Comment: Well, `Test Execution` happens with reference to a Static parameter. We have to supply the reference while we perform the `Validation`/`Assertion`. So, when the test for `ASFRDC` will be triggered, for `Assertion` you have to pass `ASFRDC` against which the `Page Title` or the `Page Contents` will be asserted.